# Disable windows dpi scaling through command line parameters?

Tags: windows, windows-10, cmd.exe, steam

I'm trying to run the original quake through steam, but I need to disable window scaling. There are like 5 executable, and I'm too lazy to do it manually. How would I disable scaling by passing arguments through steam. I'm on windows 10.